Trouble Parsing GeoJSON Map Layers from QGIS in Android App with Google Maps SDK: Alternative Solutions?"
I created a map in QGIS with 2 layers (polygons and lines) and exported them as GeoJSON files. My goal is to parse and display this custom map in an Android application. However, when attempting to use the Google Maps SDK for this purpose, I encountered an error during runtime. Are there alternative methods or file types I can use to achieve this?
I exported map layers from QGIS as GeoJSON files and attempted to parse them using the Google Maps SDK in my Android app. I expected the map to display successfully, but encountered an error during runtime. I'm seeking alternative solutions or file types that could simplify the process of displaying my custom map and viewing feature attributes

Perhaps describe the error and someone can advise how to fix that instead of starting a totally new approach.
